# Membership.generatepassword for alphanumeric characters only

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to generate alphanumeric passwords and I did this in web.config:

```
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         passwordFormat="Clear" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
```

But still i get non-alpha numeric characters. please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx

> The random password created by the ResetPassword method is not
>   guaranteed to pass the regular expression in the
>   PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property. However, the random
>   password will meet the criteria established by the
>   MinRequiredPasswordLength and MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
>   properties